# Regular Expression for the given format - start and end with alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate building name in the below format (length is 1-50)

my regex for alphanumeric and specified characters check

```
     /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._-&]+$/
```

Its showing invalid expression but when i exclude & it works fine.

```
     /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._-]+$/
```

Actual Format

> 1. Building name should use Letters, Numbers, Underscore_, Hyphen-, Period., Square-brackets[], Parentheses() ,Ampersand &
> 2. It should not start and end with any special characters continuously

Valid:

1. Empire3 State&Building[A]
2. 7Empire.State-Building(A)
3. Empire(State)_Building[A]12

Invalid:

1. @#$@$@building))
2. ().-building2
3. $buildingseven[0]&.

i am struggling for 2nd format. how to check for continuous allowed special characters at first and last. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: how to check regex for these testcases name[], &name2, name4()? any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `-` character:

```
/^(?!\W.+\W$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._\-&]+$/
```

In a character class, the `-` character signifies a range of characters (e.g `1-9`). Because the ASCII code for `&` is less than `_`, your regular expressions fails to parse correctly.

Also, to check that no special characters are at the beginning or end, use `\W` (a character other than a letter, digit or underscore) in a lookahead to check that both the start and the end are not "special characters". If you count an underscore as a special character, use `[^A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\W`.

```
var validBuildingName = /^(?!\W.+\W$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._\-&]+$/;
validBuildingName.test('(example)'); // false
validBuildingName.test('(example'); // true
validBuildingName.test('example)'); // true
validBuildingName.test('example'); // true
```

Comment: It works great.thanks. but Empire3 State&Building[A] this also invalid for above regex

Comment: @Sha: that works for me: `/^(?!\W.+\W$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._\-&]+$/.test('Empire(State)_Building[A]')`. Does that return `true`?

Comment: sorry.its working.but i gave with whitespace Empire3 State&Building[A]  []  -

Comment: @Sha: if you want whitespace to work, just add a space to the character class, so it becomes `[a-zA-Z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._\-& ]`.

Comment: name should not end with continous character after whitespace:( can you check on this 'building[12]   )  &'

Comment: see my invalid example i.e it should not accept even allowed special characters at the beginning n end.